# GetBarItemScreenRectangle Method (DevExpress 2003) should be replaced , but disappeared in DevExpress ver 13.2

Tags: c#, replace, devexpress

GetBarItemScreenRectangle Method (DevExpress 2003) should be replaced 
, but disappeared in DevExpress ver 13.2

What shoud I do ?

plz help...

Comment: Ask it also https://community.devexpress.com/forums/

Comment: @SonerGönül For now the [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) is only correct place...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the [BarItemLink.ScreenBounds](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsBarItemLink_ScreenBoundstopic) property instead:

```
Rectangle screenRectangle = barButtonItem1.Links[0].ScreenBounds;
```